# How to set custom step input value?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I need to change the step according to input number value but it does not work right. If the value is 20 step is 2 but it gives 21, 23, 25... instead of 22, 24, 26... Why? How can I solve it?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#points').on('input change', function() {
    var element = $('#points'),
      deger = element.val(),
      adim;
    // Set rules here
    if (deger < 20) {
      adim = 1;
    } else if (deger >= 20 && deger < 50) {
      adim = 2;
    } else if (deger >= 50 && deger < 100) {
      adim = 5;
    } else if (deger >= 100 && deger < 200) {
      adim = 10;
    } else {
      adim = 50;
    }
    element.attr('step', adim);
    $('#deger').text(deger);
    $('#adim').text(adim);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<div>
  Value: <span id="deger"></span>
</div>
<div>
  Current step: <span id="adim"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="points" type="number" step="4" value="12" min="1" max="10000" />
</div>
```

Comment: It's because by the time the event is fired, the value has already been changed.

Comment: How can I fix it? I want it goes as 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 24, 26...

Comment: Subtract one from the limits in your `if` clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the problem is the min attribute. Since you have min="1" when you are at 20 it goes first on 21 (because min is 1) and then starts with the correct step.
To solve simply update the min attribute also.

```
element.attr('step', adim);
element.attr('min', adim);
```

With this you can go backwards

```
$(function() {

     var adim;
  $('#points').on('input', function() {
    var element = $('#points'),
      deger = element.val()
    // Set rules here
    if (deger < 20) {
      adim = 1;
    } else if (deger == 20) {
      adim = adim === 2 ? 1 : 2;
    } else if (deger == 50) {
      adim = adim == 5 ? 2 : 5;
    } else if (deger == 100) {
      adim = adim == 10 ? 5 : 10;
    } else if (deger == 200) {
      adim = adim == 50 ? 10 : 50;
    }
    element.attr('step', adim);
    element.attr('min', adim);
    $('#deger').text(deger);
    $('#adim').text(adim);
  });
});
```

Comment: if you subtract 1 in the if clause the problem with min attribute persists. To make it work going back with the numbers, i think he needs to add a flag and update the min attr in the opposite way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works great. But I realized that if you follow these steps:
click up = 18,
click up = 19,
click up = 20,
click down = 18 instead of 19
How can I fix it?

Comment: You are right. i'm trying to figuring this out. But at this time a would say to build a simple custom number input. So you can know when clicking the up or down arrow and use setUp(step) and setDown(step) methods.

Comment: It is getting weird as is goes: click up = 46, click up = 48, click up = 50, click down = 45, click up = 50, click up = 52, click up = 54... I am lost, please help. I need it to follow steps 46, 48, 50, 55, 60 order up and down both direction.

Comment: i don't think is possible to know if you are clicking up or down, this is the problem

Comment: It works perfect, thank you very much @GabbrIssimo you saved my day.

Comment: Just one more thing: Is it possible to change default input value with the CurrentVal?

Comment: Why you want to do that? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to send new value via form but input value remains as it's default.

Comment: yes the value of the input is the same but if you try to print  `element.value` you can see is changing. Did you try this?

Comment: I figure out it is because of the disabled input value. :)